# How can I create an entry in the /Applications folder that runs a command in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, filesystem

I would like to have an item in the `/Applications` folder that will open a new terminal window and run a specific command inside. How can I create this?

Comment: Do you need the terminal window or just run the command line program?

Comment: @Mark I need the terminal window so I can see the output of the command.

Comment: Forgive me for the quesion - but what is the "applications menu" and how is it different from a text document containing the command you wish to execute?

Comment: @bmike By "Applications menu" I am referring to [this contraption](http://i.imgur.com/A6vWH.png). What do you call it? Applications place?

Comment: @ændrük That's just the `/Applications` folder. (no trolling or patronizing intended)

Comment: Thank you - i know it as the applications folder which is one of the shortcuts in a finder sidebar. Excellent clarification! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new text file starting by `#!/bin/bash` and followed by your command

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   echo 'Hello world'
   ```
2. Save with `.command` or `.tool` as extension like `myEchoCommand.command`
3. Set execute right on this file with `chmod` command.
4. You just have to double-click this newly created file, Terminal will open and execute it's content.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Automator](http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/) which Apple made part of OSX..

Create a workflow

In the workflow choose Utilities/Run Shell Script

Save as changing the File format to application - this will give a .app and choose the directory to be /Applications

EDIT to show the output.
The workflow need sto consist of three steps

1) Text->Create New TextEdit Document
2) The Utilities/Run Shell Script
3) Text->Set Contents of Textedit Document

Comment: ... and copy the resulting `.app` file into the folder `/Applications` so it shows up where you (op) said

Comment: It's not clear to me how to cause the Automator workflow to open a new terminal window and run the command inside. Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2):

[Playtypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus)

> It can be used to create native, flawlessly integrated Mac OS X applications from interpreted scripts such as shell scripts or Perl and Python programs.

Answer (score 1):

Most people just put a shell script in whatever folder they desire and make is executable with `chomd a+x`. You can use any old text editor and save the script as plain text. If you don't want to store the scripts in the `/Applications` folder that's fine as well - it won't matter where you store them as long as they are readable and executable.

If you save the file as `script.bash.command` - you won't have to associate terminal with .sh or .bash since it runs command files by default. When the script ends, the terminal session is logged out, so it will run the command and exit letting you see the results but if you want a working window you have to open another window in terminal.

Will that work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need something like [DTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm/)? It's just a shortcut away to invoke and freely installable from the AppStore. You can include it in your startup items and use it when you need it. If your command gives some output DTerm shows that in a floating window.

Comment: DTerm is just a terminal and does not produce an app

Comment: I know that, but if you check the 2nd comment to the question you would think that the person needs to see an outcome of a command not a program/app. In that light this solution could be useful without running an Automator script.