# How can I create a stand alone APP to run a terminal command

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I have the requirement to manually run the OSX maintenance scripts in OSX (Lion / Mountain Lion). I would like to create a completely stand alone application that would achieve the following goals:

- run the terminal command : `sudo periodic daily weekly monthly`
- Be executable via Finder
- Be standalone (a single file is all that is needed to execute the process so that a non technically inclined user may simple double click to run said command)
- Be portable (copy a single file to a USB flash drive or other portable media)
- Be able to be run on Mac's running OSX Lion or Mountain Lion

I do not necessarily need to see the results upon completion of execution as I can always go to /var/log directory to find out but if someone knows of a way to eliminate this extra step all the better.

I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/how-can-i-create-an-entry-in-the-applications-folder-that-runs-a-command-in-the) response but it does not meet all the requirements. I am not a coder / programmer but I can (and I am willing) to follow straightforward instructions in order to achieve my goals.

Comment: What specifically in the linked response is not appropriate for your usage other than the actual command?

Comment: I do not need users to see a terminal window and I would prefer to have a standalone .app vs a .command

Comment: Out of curiosity and assuming the given example (`sudo periodic`) is the intended command: Why do you want the user to able to kick this off manually? OS X runs this automatically for you already (and even remembers to run it later if the computer was turned off at the pre-defined time).

Comment: On some Mac's in our company due to various reasons (there are a few) the scripts may be delayed but up to as much as a couple of months to execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an Automator application that calls up an AppleScript. You will need to enter administrative credentials each time still, as I'm sure the password could be different on each system you use.

[image]

Comment: If you tell to use administrator privileges you don't need to say run `sudo` and run `periodic` directly

Comment: You're right. That was me being sloppy. I'll update the screenshot momentarily.

Comment: @bispymusic This seems to be what I'm looking for, however, when I try and build the script and execute it I get the following error: [Apple Script Error](http://imgur.com/dWVWcWo)

Comment: Please see the above comment. The AppleScript referenced in Automator does not need the word "sudo" in it, as it is already told to run with Administrator privileges. I am at work, on a PC, so I haven't been able to update the screenshot yet.

Comment: With the minor tweak this script does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to @bispymusic

Answer (score 5):

The [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84539/9388) by [bispymusic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/44060/bispymusic) should work well, but an even simpler answer (fewer layers of program to launch) would be to open **AppleScript Editor** and create a **New** script. The script is the same as above:

```
 do shell script "periodic daily weekly monthly" with administrator privileges
```

Save the script as an **application**. Done. Automator is great, but in this case, it's just calling an AppleScript, so we can cut out the automator middleman and just create an AppleScript directly.

This should meet all five of your requirements, with the technical caveat that both the automator script and the AppleScript application are technically folders and not single file. To the non-technical end user, however, they do behave like single files and can be double-clicked to run, dragged and dropped, etc.

[image]

Comment: This is also useful. I can use the for future requirements as well.

Comment: Good call @Daniel. I go to Automator so often for simple tasks that I didn't step back and realize that I could've done this purely in AppleScript.

Comment: @bispymusic Often an Automator wrapper for a one-liner is helpful. If you want to bind a one-line AppleScript to a keyboard shortcut, a Service is often the easiest way to go. If you want a script automatically applied to files dropped into a folder, again, Automator. This case is the exception where Automator doesn't add value. But your script is great; that's why I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to run a script with administrator privileges and not have to enter password each time (can't remember where I found it) :

```
property userpassword : "" -- <<< !!! DO NOT FILL !!! Script will ask if needed.

-- Will ask for password on first run
getPassword()

-- Now userpassword contains the password filled the first time
-- You can for example do :
-- do shell script "sudo ipfw list" password userpassword with administrator privileges

--
-- Your script here
--

on getPassword()
    if userpassword is "" then
        display dialog "Please enter your password:" default answer "" with hidden answer
        set userpassword to text returned of result
        -- The repeat section below is an optional error checking routine to ensure the password is valid
        set the_password to "Undefined"
        repeat until the_password is "Correct"
            try
                set theFinderPID to do shell script "ps -axww | /usr/bin/grep '[/]Finder'| awk '{print $1}' | head -1"
                do shell script "renice 1 " & theFinderPID password userpassword with administrator privileges
                do shell script "renice 0 " & theFinderPID password userpassword with administrator privileges
                set the_password to "Correct"
            on error
                display dialog "Wrong password :" default answer "" with hidden answer
                set userpassword to text returned of result
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
end getPassword
```

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing by modifying my AppleScript to `do shell script "periodic daily weekly monthly" user name "insertusernamehere" password "insertpasswordhere" with administrator privileges`. Both solutions, however, result in your password being stored in plain text in the accompanying script.

Comment: No, here, the password is not hard coded in the script.  It will be asked, checked and remembered on the user mac, more like a cookie.

Comment: @Bibou I'm not sure I understand. How is the password being encrypted or hidden in the actual script in this method? It seems to me like bispymusic is correct in that it's being stored as plain text within the script or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right. I guess I've never looked into AppleScript properties. Now I'm on a mission to find where in the script bundle it's stored! Very useful!

Comment: It is saved it the .scpt but not in plain text. It is not encrypted either, but it is harder to retrieve it than if coded in the script like : set mypassword to "something".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus), which lets you create application wrappers around scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you need this stuff anymore or not.  Could cause more problems than the app cures.
Look at this page for suggestions.  The page could be out of date.
http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/maintscripts.html

"Maintenance is a System Maintenance and Cleaning utility. It allows you to run miscellaneous tasks of system maintenance: repair permissions, run periodic scripts, reset Spotlight's Index, rebuild the LaunchServices database, delete Application, Font and System cache, and check the status of the hard disk."

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16790/maintenance

Comment: Although it's not exactly what I had in mine it's still a workable solution to my issue, thanks for the suggestion.